# Averaging columns of data

Tags: python

Ok so I'm given text files that have a header, and then each line following begins with a year, and then includes 12 numbers that correspond to the months of the year from 1977 to 2012.  I am supposed to write a program using functions to add and average the data based on year but I am struggling with how to go about this.  Any help would be great

Comment: What are the methods that you have considered? Have you done any programming before?

Comment: You tagged python in your question, do you have any python code yet for the project?  Is it possible to show the data that you need to deal with?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

Assume this is the csv:

```
year,number_1, number_2...
1911,1,2...
1912,1,3
1933,1,4,

import csv

dict_reader = csv.DictReader(open('myfile.txt'))
average_by_year = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in dict_reader:
  current_year = row['year']
  average_by_year[current_year] = (
    sum((value for key, value in row.iteritems() if key != 'year')) / 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work. It iterates through the data file, line by line, and averages the total of every column except the first.

```
with open(csvfile) as data:
    print [sum(map(int,line[:-1].split(',')[1:]))/12 for line in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a classic newbie I/O problem for coding contests (or maybe assignments)

#### Algorithm

1. Open a file with the function [file.open()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
2. Read the file line by line with the function [file.readline()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)
3. Split the read string to create a list with the function [string.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)
4. Type cast [string to int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)
5. Slice the list to separate the list of values for each month from the year at index 0 with the help of [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)
6. Using basic arithmetic functions like [sum()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) & [len()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) to compute average.
7. Bonus: Write the data to another file with the function [file.write()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

#### [SPOILER CODE] Do not hover your mouse below

> ```
>  symbol_separating_12_numbers = ','
>  f = open('filename.txt')
>  no_cases = int(f.readline())  #assuming no of cases on the first line as header
>  for case in xrange(no_cases):
>      data = [int(number) for number in f.readline().split(symbol_separating_12_numbers)]
>      months = data[1:]
>      print "%s: %s" % (data[0], sum(months)/len(months)
> ```